# How to use the word-wrap property in CSS 2.1 and validate CSS

Tags: html, xml, css

I want to validate my CSS. When I enter my website url in http://jigsaw.w3.org, I see this message: **Property word-wrap doesn't exist : break-word break-word**. How do I use word wrap code in my validated CSS,  or how to wrap words in CSS 2.1?

Comment: I don't think you can. `word-wrap` is CSS3.

Comment: Validity is no more relevant. Don't think about it.

Comment: @duri validity is still *very much* relevant under some circumstances. It is still the only reliable way to detect structural and syntax errors. It is also invaluable for quality control in an automated build process. Don't underestimate the value of validity, neither in CSS nor in HTML.

Comment: I believe that what duri means is that due to the plethora of draft standards that are being used right now, in all HTML, CSS and JS, most modern code won't validate. That's fine, because it's easy to sift through warnings such as the one mentioned here, and the real structural errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word-wrap` is CSS3 so there is no way to make it work in a CSS2 validator.

I don't know of a workaround in CSS2. You may have to either live with invalid CSS in this case, or put all the invalid rules into a separate style sheet:

```
styles.css

.text { font-size: 12px; color: red; ..... }

invalid.css

.text { word-wrap: break-word }
```

that way, the main style sheet will validate, which is good if you are using it for quality control.

Comment: Like this part about separating the "invalid" CSS into a separate file or rules ... You have any reference for that?